# Releasing different versions of same software, should you fork or branch?

Tags: git, github

I have a repository with a piece of software. I'll be releasing different versions with different features of this software, but they all share the same basic functionality and codebase. 
I've come up with the 3 possible solutions

- Should every version have their own branch within the main repo?
- Should every version be forked from the main repo?
- Completely separate repo for each version.

What other options are there and which one is the best?

Comment: If it's not too opinion-based, this seems like something more suited to Programmers.SE, as it's about the software development lifecycle, not programming specifically.

Comment: Here is an exercise for you: what, precisely, is the difference between a *branch* and a *clone*? (Doing this exercise is particularly important if you use Mercurial, where making a new clone is a more-common approach to starting a branch.) The point of this exercise, by the way, is not (just) to know the answer, but rather to make you think about how you intend to use the version control system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple questions that might guide your thinking:

1) If a change is made to one version, do you want that change reflected in the other(s)?  This includes both keeping features in sync, and applying bugfixes uniformly.

2) Do you like creating unnecessary work for yourself?

If the answer to (2) is "yes", then I certainly see the appeal of multiple repos.

If the answer to (1) is "no", then I assume that the answer to (2) must be "yes".

If the answer to (1) is "yes" and the answer to (2) is "no", then you want a single codebase - which means a single repo.  I wouldn't even use separate branches; with proper build tools, this can be handled in a single, fully integrated code base.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not pro user in managing build tools/CI, Then I would suggest using multiple branches, This way,

1. You will not mess up with whole repository
2. You can still rebase/merge/cherry-pick changes in one branch to another if required